# Deploy ROR application to a machine without internet access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I complete a simple Ror hello world application. The problem for me now is how i can deploy it another Window machine which is physically off to the Internet. I can copy files and application by USB. But how can i install gem to that machine? Does anyone have similar experience？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do [`bundle package`](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-package.1.html) to package the gems (in a machine with internet) and copy over.

You can then install local gems using bundler:

```
bundle install --local
```

Not that you could get bundle gem itself by doing:

```
gem install --local bundle.gem
```

where `bundle.gem` is obtained using `gem fetch bundler`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about your application's dependencies, take a look at the [bundle package](http://bundler.io/bundle_package.html) command, which will download all of the dependencies to `./vendor/cache`. You can then copy the `vendor` along with your application and Bundler will it instead of fetching the gems off the internet.