# rails + rbenv + bundler in prod with no internet or git allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, rbenv

I have a setup in dev using rbenv with passenger and rails.  In prod, I will have no internet access and not allowed to have git installed.  Everything will be packaged from our local git repo and deployed via rpm.  I've searched and read everything I could find, however the direction of what to use between bundle package and bundle deployment remains ambiguous to me.  So here is what I am thinking of doing - please give feedback or a solution:

In dev:

1. install rbenv for user that will be same in prod
2. install ruby + bundler + passenger
3. put .rbenv dir in local git repo to be packaged
4. in rails dir, run `bundle package --all`
5. commit ./vendor/cache to git repo as part of my project
6. in all environments, run `bundle install --local --deployment` (not sure about this part goal is to have the gems, git , etc packages install to ./vender/bundle and not contact internet, but use ./vendor/cache)
7. gitignore ./vendor/bundle

Does this work as expected, or should I take another path?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909232/deploy-ror-application-to-a-machine-without-internet-access

Comment: thanks - but I don't think that answers my complete process question.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of commands vs. normal text. It helps us help you.